# Convert timestamp from string to EST time in Synapse

Tags: sql, azure-synapse, datetime2

I am new to Synapse Data Warehouse.

Currently, I have a timestamp column named last_update_utc as string data type and it is UTC time. I need to add a new column last_update_est with timestamp as datetime2 data type convert from last_update_utc column - The conversion also needs to account for DST. You can check the sample output below:

```
id | last_update_utc (string)     | last_update_est (datetime2)
1  | 2020-02-28T17:26:47.483698Z  | 2020-02-28T12:26:47.483698Z
2  | 2021-09-03T22:59:19.093Z     | 2021-09-03T18:59:19.093Z
```

The first row, It is 5 hours of difference without DST and it is 4 hours of difference with DST. The table name is `hub.test` and initially, there are id and last_update_utc columns.

Is there a simple function or method to achieve the above task in Synapse DW ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert string to datetime2 and apply **AT TIME ZONE** to convert UTC to the required time zone.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2, '2021-09-03T22:59:19.093Z') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time'as last_update_est
```

[image]

Refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) to learn more on AT TIME ZONE implementation.

Comment: Thanks, Niharika -- I upvoted -- your code works in an Azure Synapse Analytics SQL script, connected to Lake or Dedicated.  Do you have a version of "AT TIME ZONE" that works in a NOTEBOOK, within a `%%sql` cell? (Or even in a `%%pyspark` cell, within `spark.sql`?)  I'm getting the error `no viable alternative at input 'cast(NOW() AT`???   (Note that a notebook requires `cast` instead of `convert`, and `now` instead of `getdate`.)  Here's my test code:  `select cast(NOW()  AT TIME ZONE 'Greenwich Standard Time'  AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time'  as DATETIME) AS EASTERN_TIME_NOW`

Comment: P.S. what we found for notebook `%%sql` cells:  `from_utc_timestamp(now(),'EST')`